# How to do redirects in flutter web

Tags: flutter

I'm moving my mobile project to the web, but there are some problems in the routing part.
The project works fine in its normal settings, but when we type things like /main etc instead of search, the application can't pull data because it doesn't start from splash.
I am using getx in my project, although the splash screen is set as the start, it opens the page written in the url directly.How can I run the bindings when it starts from main or how can I make the project always start from splash what is the right way?

Comment: You can try go_router

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do this, the project is based on getx routing.

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, If you want to create and inject into app some
> controller when app started, you can use that.

```
 GetMaterialApp(
    initialBinding = BindingsBuilder(() {
        // when the permanent is a true the controller will be created only once and will be available for the entire app lifetime. 
        Get.put(FirstController(), permanent: true);
        Get.put(SecondController(), permanent: true);
        /// ...Other Bindings
        ///
        ///}),)
```

> Also If you want to guard any route from not authenticated users, You
> should use the middleware. (Getx-Middleware or any)

**Ones example for Middleware**

```
class AuthGuard extends GetMiddleware {
  final bool isAuthenticated = true; // you can check user is authenticated or not

  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    ///
    /// if user is not authenticated then redirect to login page
    /// else return null
    /// return null means allow user to go to that page
    /// return RouteSettings(name: '/login') means redirect user to login page
    ///
    return isAuthenticated ? null : RouteSettings(name: '/login');
  }
}
```

**Sample Usage for Middleware**

```
GetMaterialApp(
    getPages: [
       /// 
       ///  Sample usage of GetPage with middlewares
       /// 
       GetPage(name: "login", page: () => const LoginView(),middlewares: [AuthGuard()])),
     ],),
```

Comment: what if i want it to always start from splash screen no matter what the url is. Even if refresh is done, it has to start from splash again. I tried doing it with initialRoute ,onGenerateRoute but it didn't work

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: The website can be used normally, but it throws an error when the http://localhos/#/Onboarding link is searched or the page is refreshed. Starting from /mySplashScreen all the time can solve my problem for a short time.

Comment: Did you try this ever ?
unknownRoute: GetPage(name: '/notfound', page: () => UnknownRoutePage()),

Comment: Maybe it can help if you define SplashScreen on Unknown Route page.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I want the website to always start from splash screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255204/discussion-between-rasityilmaz-and-deniz).